# Jquery: Can't fade in <span> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I have have a span element that I want to let fade in from display none.
Fading out works perfectly fine but Fading in just doesnt work,

Here is the css of the span element:

```js
$(".button_5").hover(function () {
        $(".box5 span.info").fadeIn();
    });

//The fade out just works fine:

    $(".button_5").hover(function () {
        $(".box5 span.info").fadeOut();
    });
```

```css
.box5 span.info:before{
        content:"15 vacatures";
        margin:0;
        padding:0 0 28px 0;
        display:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col1">
        <div class="button_5">
            <div class="box5">
                <br><br>
                <span class="title"></span><br/>
                <span class="info"></span>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: I don't get what you tried to do. Fading out and in are supposed to happen at the same time ? Can you describe the goal and make a fiddle ?

Comment: That is not the css of the span.  That is the css for a pseudo-element nested within a child of the span.

Comment: If you start the `span` with `display:none` it works well: http://jsfiddle.net/oqfhuLzn/2/

Comment: Sorry I just metioned that the fadeOut() works fine, while when I just change that to fadeIn() and add display:none to the opacity,fade In doesnt work

Comment: LcSalazar THank You This DiD IT!!

Comment: Okay, posted as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like

```
$(".button_5").hover(function () {
   $(".box5 span.info").fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oqfhuLzn/2/

Answer (score 1):

You must add `display: none` to your `span.info` element, in order to fade in...

http://jsfiddle.net/oqfhuLzn/3/

```
.box5 span.info {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button_5").hover(function () {
    $(".box5 span.info").fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(".box5 span.info").fadeOut();
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/19ykuar2/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you remove the `:before` and change the `display: 0` to `display:none;`

Take a look to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qxu1gnme/1/